# Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

After Updating Android Studio and Gradle i get below error.

[image]

**What i have tried:**
1. I'm using a proxy and have tried automatic and manual proxy settings. check connection works and is successful, android sdk updates also shows but libraries and repositories not downloaded from google(), jcenter(), etc.
2. run as admin doesn't fix the problem.
3. the same proxy was working correctly before, i also tried other proxies which didn't work.
4. i am using windows 10, gradle 4.4, android studio 3.1.
5. reverting back to version 3.0 didn't fix the problem.
6. reverting back to gradle 4.1 didn't fix the problem.
7. clean project, invalidate cache + restart doesn't work.

Update: the problem comes from the version 3.1 and upward, it seems there was some sort of change from version 3.1 in android studio with proxy authentication. i still can't fix it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can u please provide your distrivutionURl in Graddle wrapper

Comment: I notice that the gradle.properties file states that configuration in the IDE will override the settings in that file. Perhaps that's the issue? Have you worked through the IDE's docs on this? https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

Comment: @TominB sure. distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Comment: have you tried building your app from command line? You can just do `gradlew assemble` this will start downloading the dependencies. Sometimes its strange with Androd-studio that it doesn't recognize the proxy changes. I manage to solve it by running from command line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898587/android-studio-3-1-proxy-configuration-unable-to-set-https-user-password-for-g/51686033#51686033

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm using this two lines and works fine for me.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=HostIP
systemProp.http.proxyPort=portNumber
```

If you need to use authentication add these two more lines:

```
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
```

I never had to use https settings.

> Be sure that Http proxy which you are using is able to bypass Https protocol. I suggest using sites like free-proxy-list.net, hidemy.name/en/proxy-list which even provide proxy servers without authentication.
>
> But first test the proxy in browser.

IF you really need to use the proxy server which you have (Being behind a firewall or something).
The alternative way of binding proxy is to use softwares like [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/download/) [Alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/proxifier/?license=free). This app can force all connection through proxy [Rules Screenshot](https://www.proxifier.com/screenshots/rules.png).

Comment: as shown in the 2nd picture i already used all of those lines.

Comment: @MasoudMohammadi my point was to just use HTTP and I also had an alternative method for you ;)

Comment: sorry for not getting the point at the first place, indeed problem got solved after removing https lines.

Comment: I'll be glad to get an approved answer.  Also the reason I think its not working can may be government limitations !

Answer (score 9):

Go to `C:\Users\windows user\.gradle` which is mostly default in most of the systems. Open `Gradle.properties` file (You can Use Visual Studio Code editor ).
Just view the proxy setting and modify them if required.

For me `password` was blank, I filled the password field and Gradle worked perfectly.

The above thing works only if u enabled proxy in Android studio.

Comment: Thank you. It work. Turn out it only save the proxyUser but not the proxyPassword so I need to set the password

Answer (score 7):

To solve this problem I'm using this code lines :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=yourProxyHost
systemProp.http.proxyPort=yourPort
systemProp.http.proxyUser=yourUser
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=yourPass

systemProp.https.proxyHost=yourProxyHost
systemProp.https.proxyPort=yourPort
systemProp.https.proxyUser=yourUser
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=yourPass
```

and then restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it this way:

1. Android Studio (my version 3.1.2)->Settings->Http proxy->Manual
   proxy configuration (!!!)->Enter login and password->Check
   connection
2. Possible restart Android Studio, I don't remember
3. When gradle build was started then window with proxy settings with
   HTTP and HTTPs(!) for gradle was opened-->Apply settings
4. After that file "gradle.properties (Global properties)" was
   automatically created, inside you must enter a password:

   systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
       systemProp.http.proxyUser=domain/login
       systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
       systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
       systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy_host
       #systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=
       systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy_host
       systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
       #systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=
       systemProp.https.proxyUser=domain/login

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem in the following way :

a. Android studio (3.4.1) set the proxy as auto detect

b. Instant run disabled

c. Enable embedded maven repository ( settings->build,execution and deployment->gradle->android studio)

d. Use local gradle distribution (setting->build execution and deployment->gradle->use local gradle distribution->provide path for gradle)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Adding proxy settings alone does not work for me.

By adding one more line `systemProp.jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""` to `gradle.properties`, the problem is solved.

Comment: Working for me. Some explanation would help more.

Comment: Didnt work for Android Studio bumblebee

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running react-native application. If your on office vpn network then re-connecting may help you. If that doesn't resolve, switching between vpn or restart should help.