# Android Studio 3.1: Proxy configuration: Unable to set https user password for git operations

Tags: android, git, android-studio, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

I recently upgraded my Android Studio from 3.0 to 3.1. In 3.0, I used to set proxy configuration in *gradle.properties*(Global properties) file, which includes setting *systemProp.https.proxyPassword* among others. However, I am unable to set this variable in 3.1. It seems like a design decision to prevent writing user password in an user-accessible file. However, how to go about setting the same?

Currently, whenever I set systemProp.https.proxyPassword, it gets overwritten with blank field next time I open Android Studio. And even after setting this variable again in *gradle.properties* (with global scope), I am unable to do git pull/push operations. It returns the following error:

> Update canceled
>   Fetch failed: unable to access 'https://github.com/user_name/repo_name.git/': Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use `gradle.properties` ? if not did you try to set your proxy directly into Android Studio ? (`Settings...>Appearance & behavior > System Settings > Http Proxy`)

Comment: yes I did try setting proxy in the way you described, but it sets HTTP proxy only. However, I am unsure about how to set HTTPS proxy, which perhaps is resulting in this error.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am facing the same issue now, and I can't make Android Studio 3.1 work with a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

One solution which worked for me is the following.

1. **Uncheck** the box which says 'Require authentication' in the pop-up window which comes when you click on the proxy-error message. Note that the password section is 'N/A' in this pop-up message (i.e., there is option only to enter the username. It says you need to add the password in the gradle.properties file).

[image: Pop up window where you have to uncheck the proxy authentication]

2. I set the following in gradle.properties (replace *xxxx* with your details)

   ```
   systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxxx
   systemProp.https.proxyUser=xxxx
   systemProp.https.proxyHost=xxxx
   systemProp.https.proxyPassword=xxxx
   systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxxx
   systemProp.http.proxyUser=xxxx
   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxxx
   systemProp.http.proxyHost=xxxx
   ```
3. Go to File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy. Enter your proxy details (with username and password here)

Answer (score 2):

C:\Users\Admin.gradle\gradle.properties
open this file in your notepad and update your password
both for
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=

it worked for me !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can also write:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxxx
systemProp.https.proxyUser=xxxx
systemProp.https.proxyHost=xxxx
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=xxxx
systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxxx
systemProp.http.proxyUser=xxxx
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxxx
systemProp.http.proxyHost=xxxx
```

in %UserHome%/.gradle/gradle.properties
Then, if Android studio ask you about proxy, just ignore it... It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was with file
etc/hosts

After adding required IP and host I got success.